# Postgres insert error in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-postgresql

For some reason, I cannot get ActiveRecord to correctly format the insert statement when using an array type column. It seems to want to escape the Postgres notation:

`{"val1", "val2", "val3"}` into `\{\"val1\", \"val2\", \"val3\"\}`

Resulting in an error:

`PG::Error: ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information`

Am I running my db commands wrong? `rake db:seed` and `bundle exec rake db:seed` cause this error as well as running migrations.

I'm running Rails 3.2.13 and Postgres 9.3.1

Comment: Are you using the Rails way to serialize array attributes when saving arrays into db?

Comment: No, it's a list. i.e. Thing.create({title: 'xxx', slugs: ["x", "y" "z"]})

Comment: [Use Rails' `serialize` method.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html). Read up on "Saving arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects in text columns"

Comment: @dmtri.com he wants to use Postgres.  James could you please provide more code/context?

Comment: @RyanB, using `serialize` method to store array should work for postgresql as well.

Answer (score 2):

The Rails3 version of ActiveRecord doesn't understand PostgreSQL arrays natively so it is falling back to "I don't know what it is so I'll pretend it is a string" mode. If you install [`postgres_ext`](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext) then you'll be able to use arrays properly:

```
Model.where(:some_array_column => [2, 3, 5, 6, 11]).to_sql
# SELECT "models".* FROM "models" WHERE "models"."some_array_column" = '{2,3,5,6,11}'
```

and inserting a `%w[val1 val2 val3]` array should work similarly.

Comment: In case someone needs to have array of string in the strong params all you have to do is include [postgres_ext](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext) and the add in the list of params to permit `:some_array_column => []`